# Como faço para consumir esse json no react?

Tags: react-native

gostaria de consumir esse json mas esta dando muitos erros

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json

gostaria de mostrar no FlatList

Comment: Seja bem-vindo Eduardo. Para que seja mais fácil alguém ajuda-lo a resolver o problema que você está enfrentando seria melhor você criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel). Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código que está desenvolvendo e especifique exatamente qual a dificuldade está tendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não testei aqui mas acredito que isso resolva:
Faça a requisição com axios ou fetch, pode ser feita por exemplo em componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', { method: 'GET' })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }))
}
```

Assim você vai ter a lista nos States pronta para ser renderizada na FlatList:

```
<FlatList
  data={data.movies}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
    >
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text>{item.releaseYear}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Veja a documentação para tirar mais dúvidas: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist
Dica: [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html) é uma ótima biblioteca pra criar flatlists, dá uma olhada nela.

Comment: Para complementar, na documentação do React Native, o exemplo do uso do fetch é exatamente a resposta para a pergunta. Podendo acessar em: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-fetch)